# Fastest sort algorithm for Rational numbers in double precision

Tags: java, double, sorting

I am looking for the fastest algorithm to sort numbers after FFT transformation - only real numbers in abs. values)=rational numbers in double precision, for 1d array of 2^19 elements. I think the megre sort will be best...

Comment: You can't expect people to spend time thinking about your issue when you don't seem to want to spend time yourself formulating it properly...

Comment: fastest waz how to sorting array with posittive elemtnts/rational elements. ,on RAm not depends /numer of elements 2^19

Comment: I think its clearlz evident, what i need

Comment: 1. Try several sorting algorithms. 2. Pick the fastest one.

Comment: @LukeNumerati A good start would be to re-read your messages and remove typos **before** you press "SEND".

Comment: For the record, it matters little what **you** think about the clarity of your question, unless you plan to ask and answer it all by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about sorting a `double[]`, then use `Arrays.sort`. It's a quicksort derivative.

If what you have is an array of objects representing double-precision fractions, then that class needs to implement `Comparable`, but once again you'll be best served by `Arrays.sort(Object[])`, which uses timsort (as of Java 7). But be careful, performance is then in your hands: don't mess up the implementation of `compareTo`.

Comment: In Oracle JDK 1.6 it is mergesort, since 1.7 it is timsort.

Comment: @thomasjungblut You need to check your facts. Primitive arrays are sorted using quicksort. The source coode is freely available.

Comment: true that `The sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info `Arrays.sort` in Java7 uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort):

> Timsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data. It was invented by Tim Peters in 2002 for use in the Python programming language. The algorithm finds subsets of the data that are already ordered, and uses the subsets to sort the data more efficiently. This is done by merging an identified subset, called a run, with existing runs until certain criteria are fulfilled. Timsort has been Python's standard sorting algorithm since version 2.3. It is now also used to sort arrays in Java SE 7, and on the Android platform.

Comment: Java uses quicksort for primitive arrays. This trivial fact seems to have been lost in all the hype around timsort introduced in Java7 for reference-typed arrays.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik -- yup that is right. For primitives data types... The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

Answer (score 0):

What algorithm to use depends not so much on what kind of objects you are sorting, but rather on how messed up they are.

See http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ for a comparison of how different standard algorithms perform in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just sorting ~1/2 million elements, you have many options. You can probably get away with the standard sort algorithm included with whatever language you are using.

Seems there will be pretty good variability among the elements, but I'm not sure if FFT transformations produce arrays with large runs of already sorted numbers. If so, you will want to avoid Quicksort. I hear Timsort is very good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

- Arrays.sort() must be your choice.
- Give an index field to your Rational object and use it at your compareTo() instead something like

> this.numerator * other.denominator - this.denominator * other.numerator

Good luck!